# Can I add a systemd order dependency to a specific kernel module?

Tags: systemd, kernel-modules

I am developing for an embedded linux system and using a kernel module that when probed loads a settings file from a specific filesystem path.  If it cannot find the settings file, the probe attempt does not error out but simply loads with incorrect settings.  As I am using systemd, this module is loaded in parallel with everything that is not explicitly marked as needing to be loaded before this module, and that appears to include the systemd unit that mounts the filesystem that holds this settings file.  (The architecture of the embedded linux system requires this settings file be on a separate filesystem from the root filesystem.)

The kernel module in question is part of a wifi driver that is loaded by systemd-udev.  It doesn't seem like each kernel module loaded by udev is listed as a systemd unit though, so it isn't clear how I would force this module to not be probed until after a specific filesystem is mounted.  Is this something that can be done in systemd?

Comment: Do you know by what the module is loaded, which unit causes that?

Comment: My understanding is that once the kernel finishes bringing up the sdio bus that the wifi chip is connected to, it sends out a uevent that the wifi hardware is ready for a driver, and systemd-udev is listening for uevents.  Then systemd-udev looks up the required kernel module in /lib/modules/.../modules.alias and loads the module and all of its dependencies.  I am currently looking into whether the loading of systemd-udev itself can be deferred until after mounting this filesystem -- I am not sure whether systemd-udev is itself required to mount the filesystem...